Blockhash not found when using solana CLI
Im trying to deploy a program and close buffer accounts.
I am using a payed quicknode RPC for that, some problem happens with the public endpoint quite often. After a few tries it usually works.
Does that mean the RPC node it 150 block behind? Or what could be the reason for it to sometimes work sometimes not?


you can try with proper priority fees set - https://solana.gears.bot/deploy-cmd

I think this is a general bug in the Solana CLI. I might start running a debug build to help isolate it, since it's definitely annoying

The "blockhash not found" error usually means that your transaction is referencing a blockhash that's too old. Solana transactions must be processed within a certain number of blocks of when the blockhash was generated.
Here’s what might be happening:

Your RPC node might be lagging or not updated.
High network congestion can cause delays.

To fix it:

Ensure your RPC node is up-to-date and reliable.
Resubmit your transaction if it fails.

Yes, an RPC node being 150 blocks behind could cause this issue. Consider using a different, more reliable RPC or retrying after some time.
Please try with helius rpc: https://www.helius.dev/
